# Applying dropout to input layer in LSTM network (Keras)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, dropout

Is it possible to apply dropout to input layer of LSTM network in Keras?

If this is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(look_back, input_length), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

The goal is to achieve the effect of:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(look_back, input_length), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Comment: Did you try? Ther was an error? You just need to set the input_shape to your Dropout layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#first-example-a-densely-connected-network), in which your model would be written as:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(input_shape), dtype='int32')
x = Dropout(0.5)(inputs)
x = LSTM(10,return_sequences=False)(x)
```

define your output layer, for example:

```
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
```

and then build the model:

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```